# Frontend AJAX Media Upload returning 404

Tags: ajax, uploads, attachments

I am building a custom registration form for users where they have to upload an image of government ID. Using AJAX for submission.

The handler function always returning a 404 status error, no matter what. Whereas, the user gets registered and the file gets uploaded. Please tell me where I am doing wrong?

Here are my codes..

Form HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-3 mt-4">
    <form id="vrform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="reg_firstname" type="text" placeholder="First name*" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="reg_lastname" required type="text" placeholder="Last name*">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="reg_vmail" required type="email" placeholder="Email ID*">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="reg_phone" required type="tel" placeholder="Contact Number*">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="reg_businessname" type="text" placeholder="Business Name (If applicable)">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group autocomplete">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Type of Payment" id="myInputpay" name="reg_myInputpay" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="reg_address" required type="text" placeholder="Street address line 1*">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="reg_address1" type="text" placeholder="Street address line 2">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="reg_city" required type="text" placeholder="City/Village/Town">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group autocomplete">
            <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" name="reg_country" required placeholder="Country*">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="reg_password1" required type="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group autocomplete">
            <input class="form-control" name="reg_password2" required type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="border p-4 mb-3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="reg_govtid" placeholder="Government Issued ID Number" required>                      
                        <label class="mt-1 ml-3">
                            <i><small>Upload Supporting Government ID*</small></i></label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="govtiddoc" name="reg_govtiddoc" type="file" placeholder="" required>
            <p class="ulresponse"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 form-group termsandconditionscheck">
            <label><input name="reg_tc" required type="checkbox" class="mr-2" checked>By creating an account, you agree to our <a href="#">terms & conditions.</a></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'pnvr', 'pnvr' );?>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success text-uppercase pt-2 pb-2 btn-lg" value="REGISTER">
            <img id="rsubmit" class="d-none mx-auto" alt="Loading.." src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/images/ajax.gif">
            <div id="resmsg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var vrForm = $('#vrform');
    $(vrForm).submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#resmsg').html('');
        var pass = $('input[name="reg_password1"]').val();
        var pass2 = $('input[name="reg_password2"]').val();
        if ( pass.length < 8 ) {
            $('#resmsg').html('<span class="text-danger">Password should be 8 charecters or more.</span>');
            $('input[name="reg_password1"]').focus();
            return false;
        }
        if ( pass != pass2 ) {
            $('#resmsg').html('<span class="text-danger">Passwords doesn\'t match.</span>');
            $('input[name="reg_password2"]').focus();
            return false;
        }
        $('#rsubmit').removeClass('d-none').addClass('d-flex');
        
        var myformData = new FormData(vrForm[0]);
        myformData.append('action', 'pn_reg_vendors');
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: myformData,
            dataType: "json",
            url: ajaxurl,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $('#rsubmit').removeClass('d-flex').addClass('d-none');
                if (data == 'success' ) {
                    $(vrForm)[0].reset();
                    $('#resmsg').html('<span class="text-success">Registration successful. You\'ll receive and email once your account is approved.</span>');
                } else if ( data == 'exists' ) {
                    $('input[name="reg_vmail"]').focus();
                    $('#resmsg').html('<span class="text-danger">This email already exists.</span>');
                } else {
                    $('#resmsg').html('<span class="text-danger">Something went wrong. Please reload the page and try again.</span>');
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                //if fails     
            }
        });
        
    });
});
</script>
```

Handler Function:

```
function pn_reg_vendors() {
    
    $status = '';
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['pnvr'], 'pnvr' ) ) {
        $status = 'failed';
    } else {
        $usere = get_user_by( 'email', $_POST['reg_vmail'] );
        if ( $usere ) {
            $status = 'exists';
        } else {
            
            $first_name = $_POST['reg_firstname'];
            $last_name = $_POST['reg_lastname'];
            $email = $_POST['reg_vmail'];
            $phone = $_POST['reg_phone'];
            $business = $_POST['reg_businessname'];
            $paymentType = $_POST['reg_myInputpay'];
            $address = $_POST['reg_address'];
            $address1 = $_POST['reg_address1'];
            $city = $_POST['reg_city'];
            $country = $_POST['reg_country'];
            $password = $_POST['reg_password1'];
            $govtid = $_POST['reg_govtid'];
            
            $user_id = wp_insert_user(array(
                'user_pass' => $password,
                'user_login' => $email,
                'user_nicename' => strtolower( str_replace( ' ', '-', $first_name . '-' . $last_name )),
                'user_email' => $email,
                'display_name' => $first_name . ' ' . $last_name,
                'nickname' => $first_name,
                'first_name' => $first_name,
                'last_name' => $last_name,
                'show_admin_bar_front' => false,
                'role' => 'pending',
            ));
            
            if ( !is_wp_error($user_id) ) {
                
                require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
                require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
                require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
                $atid = media_handle_upload( 'reg_govtiddoc', 0 );
                if ( is_wp_error( $atid ) ) {
                    $imgid = '';
                } else {
                    $imgid = $atid;
                }
                
                update_user_meta( $user_id, '_pn_first_name', $first_name );
                update_user_meta( $user_id, '_pn_last_name', $last_name );
                update_user_meta( $user_id, '_pn_email', $email );
                update_user_meta( $user_id, '_pn_phone', $phone );
                update_user_meta( $user_id, '_pn_business_name', $business );
                update_user_meta( $user_id, '_pn_payment_type', $paymentType );
                update_user_meta( $user_id, '_pn_address', $address );
                update_user_meta( $user_id, '_pn_address1', $address1 );
                update_user_meta( $user_id, '_pn_city', $city );
                update_user_meta( $user_id, '_pn_country', $country );
                update_user_meta( $user_id, '_pn_govtid', $govtid );
                update_user_meta( $user_id, '_pn_govtid_img', $imgid );
                
                $status = 'success';
            } else {
                $status = 'failed';
            }
        }
    }
    //header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($status);
    wp_die();
}
//add_action( 'wp_ajax_pn_reg_vendors', 'pn_reg_vendors' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_pn_reg_vendors', 'pn_reg_vendors' );
```

Comment: If your handler does get executed, then it's probably a plugin or custom code that caused the error 404 - are you very sure it's 404 and that it's not actually from another request on the page? Try inspecting the network requests.

Comment: @SallyCJ I already inspected network requests. Cleaned the network request log before initiating the AJAX call. There are no other simultaneous request. I guess the problem is with the file upload part. If I comment out that section, the codes fully work.

Comment: Honestly, your code seems fine to me, so I suggest you to try deactivating your plugins to check if it's a plugin issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the define of the ajaxurl variable. The 404 is inevitable.

Usually, you need to define it in your function or directly in a wp_localize_script action.

Dont't forget to replace the wp_ajax_pn_reg_vendors, to make it work, even the user is not yet connect.